# Switch between frames in tkinter using functions

Tags: button, tkinter, switch-statement, frames

From the answer given by Bryan Oakley to the question “Switch between two frames in tkinter”, I trie to change how the button works in page two.

On page one, with `command=lambda: controller.show_frame(“StartPage”)`, it works as it should.

On page two, I want to add something and then go back but it does not work.

Why does my callback not get called?

```
import tkinter as tk                # python 3
from tkinter import font  as tkfont # python 3

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page Two",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))
        button1.pack()
        button2.pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 2", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=self.go_to())
        button.pack()
    def go_to(self):
        # Add something to do            
        self.controller.show_frame("StartPage")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `command` keyword argument of `Button` takes a function.
You create your button with `tk.Button(self, ..., command=self.go_to())`, so the command is `self.go_to()`, which evaluates to `None`.

Why is that so?
`go_to` is defined as follows:

```
def go_to(self):
    # Add something to do 
    self.controller.show_frame("StartPage")
```

So when Python comes across `command=self.go_to()`, it calls `go_to`, and passes the returned value to the `command` option.
This value is `None` (implied by the absence of a `return` statement), so your command is `None`, and your button has no effect.

You need to remove the parentheses, so has to have `tk.Button(self, ..., command=self.go_to)`.

Comment: Thank you. It was in front of my eyes and I could not see it. Thanks

Comment: Just one moe question, if go_to uses a parameter to do something and then it goes back to StartPage, how do you implement it (because now the parenthesis are needed)?

Comment: @ogeretal Either wrap it around an argument-less function, or use a lambda, such as `command=lambda: self.go_to(x, y)`. That lambda means "that function that takes no argument and that calls f with x and y", so it's a function as expected.

Comment: Thanks again. And yes, the question is duplicated